# DataSet serialization and OutOfMemoryException

Tags: serialization, dataset, asp.net-3.5

I've got a `DataSet` with about 250k Rows and 80 Columns causing `StringBuilder` to throw an OutOfMemoryException (@System.String.GetStringForStringBuilder(String value, Int32 startIndex, Int32 length, Int32 capacity)) when calling .GetXml() on my dataset.

As I read [here (last paragraph)](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vsofficedeveloper/archive/2008/10/10/stringbuilder-outofmemoryexception.aspx) this can be overcome by using binary representation instead of xml, which sounds logical. 
So I set the RemotingFormat-property on my dataset to binary but the issue still occurs.

I had a closer look to the GetXml-implementation and there seems to be no distinction based on the RemotingFormat. Instead, I found out that GetXmlSchemaForRemoting considers RemotingFormat, but this method is internal so I can't call it from the outside. It is called by private SerializeDataSet which is called by public GetObjectData.
GetObjectData itself seems to be for custom serialization.

How can I binary (de-)serialize my dataset? Or call at least GetXml without throwing exceptions? Did I overlook any dataset property?

Comment: Of course there ARE exceptions but I think in general, if you've got 250k of anything and you're seeing OutOfMemoryExceptions, you should reconsider your approach.

Comment: Returning and *keeping* 250K rows in memory is a rather bad design. Sounds like your *real* question is how to export those rows to some file? Or send it to someone else? What are you *really* trying to do?

Comment: see you cannot see all the records at once right? so try going for pagenation approach getting records not all at once. Am not sure but you can also try getting data in chunks for large data.

Comment: @Panagiotis Kanavos: A job is requesting the data to do something with it. As I wrote it is no problem to get chunks from the database, but I'm interested in another solution (and wonder why that build in binary serialization won't work). I agree that it is much data, maybe 600mb, but this should still be serializable.

Comment: As all others said, you are doing it the wrong way. Loading 600MB in memory and trying to write it at once may require little code but doesn't scale. If you aren't tied to the dataset schema (which is not very interoperable anyway) you should read the rows with a DataReader and write them using an XmlWriter. Or use SSIS to automate the entire process. This holds for any database, for any language. You wouldn't have better luck if you used IBM DB2 and C++ or Java

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The link you provided in you question is from 2008.

There is some more new discussions:

[dotnespider 2009](http://www.dotnetspider.com/forum/234222-System-OutOfMemoryException-thrown-case-huge-data.aspx)

and also from [SO 2011](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5092510/system-outofmemoryexception-when-filling-dataadapter).

The last one is about problem with `DataAdapter` while reading 150K records, but the answer can be also interestin for you:

> The first thing that I'd check is how many columns you are returning,
>   and what their data types are.

and

> ...you are either returning way more fields than you need, or perhaps
>   that some of the fields are very large strings or binary data. Try
>   cutting down the select statement to only return the fields that are
>   absolutely needed for the display.
>
> If that doesn't work, you may need to move from a DataTable to a list
>   of a custom data type (a class with the appropriate fields).

from the [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5092595/502950)

Comment: I think .NET should be able to process this data in binary format, with much less overhead that's why I'm interested in a solution where I don't need to process data in the frontend. Something like this: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/tess/archive/2008/09/02/outofmemoryexceptions-while-remoting-very-large-datasets.aspx but as I wrote this doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 1):

As you discovered there is no built in way to serialize datasets as binary.

The only way to serialize your dataset as binary data is to implement your own formatter. 
start here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163911.aspx

Comment: This is no new link to me. If you check out my link in the comment to MikroDel's answer you'll find it there, too. There is a suggestion to change the serialization to binary and this leads back to my question...

Comment: The link in the first comment discusses the same issue but Dino's article covers the why not just the how and doesn't change the answer in any case XML serialization doesn't scale and your only solution is to create a binary formatter.

Comment: But this should be build-in already according to http://blogs.msdn.com/b/tess/archive/2008/09/02/outofmemoryexceptions-while-remoting-very-large-datasets.aspx: ds.RemotingFormat = SerializationFormat.Binary;

Comment: I believe that this was never implemented so even if you set the format to binary you still get XML

Comment: It is recommended from a microsoft official [here](blogs.msdn.com/b/tess/archive/2008/09/02/outofmemoryexceptions-while-remoting-very-large-datasets.aspx) so it should work somehow.