# Make a new table with the other tables

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, database

When I make query

```
SELECT a.ID, 
       a.Employee, 
       b.Name, 
       b.[Open Date] 
  FROM tblEmployees a, 
       Stores b
```

it works well, but when I make query

```
SELECT a.ID, 
       a.Employee, 
       b.Name, 
       b.[Open Date], 
       c.Task 
  FROM tblEmployees a, 
       Stores b, 
       tblTasks c
```

It doesn't work.

It keeps giving an error on `sda.Fill(dt)`:

> System.OutOfMemoryException: 'System.OutOfMemoryException'

```
private DataTable GetData() 
{
    string connString = @"Data Source=aa.database.windows.net;Initial Catalog=aa;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=aa;Password=aa";
    string query = "SELECT a.ID, a.Employee, b.Name, b.[Open Date], c.Task FROM tblEmployees a, Stores b, tblTasks c";
    using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connString))
    {
        using (SqlCommand comm = new SqlCommand(query))
        {
            using (SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter())
            {
                comm.Connection = con;
                sda.SelectCommand = comm;
                using (DataTable dt = new DataTable())
                {
                    sda.Fill(dt);
                    return dt;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: How many records that query returns?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [system.outofmemoryexception When filling DataAdapter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5092510/system-outofmemoryexception-when-filling-dataadapter)

Comment: Your using the old-style join syntax: `FROM tblEmployees, Stores, tblTasks` will return the Cartesian product of all these tables (`CROSS JOIN`), which is likely frickin' huge -- and not at all what you want. Read up on `INNER JOIN`. If you *do* want all tables in one query somehow, you want a `UNION ALL` (but you'll get a weird set of columns) or else just three separate queries into three separate tables.

Comment: Your quesry is **cartesian join** with (potentially) **billions** of records. It seems that you omitted `where` clause

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alternatively, you could make the joins within the where clause:

```
SELECT a.ID, 
       a.Employee, 
       b.Name, 
       b.[Open Date], 
       c.Task 
  FROM tblEmployees a, 
       Stores b, 
       tblTasks c
  where a.id = b.employeeid  -- clearly made up these name
  and  c.taskownerid= a.id
```

BTW, the title of this question seems much different than the actual request.

Answer (score 2):

The data from all tables are linked? if so you must need to explicit this link using join statement

```
SELECT a.ID, 
       a.Employee, 
       b.Name, 
       b.[Open Date], 
       c.Task 
  FROM tblEmployees a
  JOIN Stores b on b.id = a.id_store -- explicit our link here
  JOIN Tasks c on c.id = a.id_task -- explicit our link here
```

but if you're trying to request data from 3 distinct tables its better do 3 requests